# Prove or disprove that AB=AC $\implies$ B=C

Tags: matrices

I proved it as follows but I'm not so sure about it.

A, B and C are square matrices of the same order.

Assume  $ B \neq C $

$$ AB \neq AC$$
$$ B \neq C \implies AB \neq AC$$
$$ \neg ( AB \neq AC) \implies \neg ( B \neq C ) $$
$$AB =AC \implies B=C $$

Comment: In general, one cannot expect to prove anything about something concrete (here maybe the integers, or the reals, it has not been made clear) by manipulation of logical symbols alone.

Comment: What is the domain we're talking about?  What does the $\;.\;$ operator mean?

Comment: The claim that $B\ne C \implies A.B \ne A.C$ is probably incorrect.  Although as @MarnixKlooster says, it's impossible to say without defining what kind of objects $A$, $B$, and $C$ are and what the $.$ operator is.

Comment: Forgive me I forgot to mention that A,B and C are matrices.

Comment: Can you think of a non-zero matrix $A$ such that $A^2=0$?

Answer (score 3):

What if $A$ is zero? ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: What if $.$ is addition?  You shouldn't post an answer to an underspecified question.

Comment: With the balance of probability beyond a given threshold I think it makes sense to assume the most obvious choice. This one is perhaps debatable; if OP gives any indication to the contrary I'd happily delete. (For my side of the debate: the title doesn't even have a period symbol, and usually concatenation implies a multiplication operation, and usually a multiplication operation is in the context of numbers, especially when no other context is given.)

Comment: You're probably right, but one immediate counterexample is if $A$, $B$, and $C$ are members of a group, in which case the claim is true.

Comment: "." Is not addition, I never thought one would consider it as a different operator.

Answer (score -2):

If A be non-zero,then it is true.

Comment: Depends on the context. There are many valid contexts, e.g. in abstract algebra, where your claim is simply wrong. The main problem is that the OP did not specify what kind of objects $A,B,C $ are, and what $AB$ means et cetera.

Comment: What if $A$ is nonzero and singular?